# Quit command giving error in node-redis

Tags: node.js, redis

```
function Redis(){

this.redis=require('redis-node');
this.client =this.redis.createClient(6377, '127.0.0.1', {detect_buffers: true});
this.client.auth("pwd");

}

module.exports=Redis;

Redis.prototype.setKeyValue=function(key,value){

var obj=this;
this.client.get(key,function(err,res){

    if(res==null){


        obj.client.set(key,value,function (err, result) {
            console.log(result); 
            obj.client.quit();//here im getting error as client doesn't have method quit
         });

    }
    else{

        console.log('Sorry!!!key is already exist');
    }
});


  };
```

Comment: Don't forget to validate an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i came to know that

```
https://github.com/bnoguchi/redis-node
```

In the above library client does not have a method called client.quit() instead of that we can use client.close().

```
https://github.com/mranney/node_redis
```

Here it has a method called quit to close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The prefered library for NodeJS is inded node_redis.
Moreover, your code is not protected against [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) (between `get` and `set` the key could be `set` by another process) hopefully Redis provides a command for that: **[setnx](http://redis.io/commands/setnx)**.

Finally your code could be simplified as:

```
var redis = require("redis");

function Redis() {
  this.client = redis.createClient(6377, '127.0.0.1', {
    detect_buffers: true,
    auth_pass: "pwd"
  });
}

/**
 * @param {String} key   key name
 * @param {String} value key value
 * @param {Function} f(err, ret)
 */
Redis.prototype.setKeyValue = function(key, value, f) {
  this.client.setnx(key, value, f);
};

module.exports = Redis;
```

However I don't get why you don't use directly redis client api instead of wrapping it inside a Redis function?